# Change a column based on another column value

Tags: bash, awk, sed, text-processing

I have a file with hundreds of records like this

```
100,502030,0,444,RSVYU,10
101,501412,1,555,DDGTH,11
102,502269,0,222,DDERF,60
103,508877,2,111,SDEFV,23
```

How to replace the value of the **4th** column with **000** if the value of the **3rd** column is **0**

I researched a lot and couldn't find a solution. So far I got this

```
cat testfile.txt | sed -n -r 's/^[0-9]*,[0-9]*,0/000/p'
```

But it replaces the first part

Comment: This is a very basic use of awk. Please do some research before posting here.

Answer (score 5):

With awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $3=="0" {$4="000"}1' file
```

> `FS`: input field separator
>
> `OFS`: output field separator

Output:

```
100,502030,0,000,RSVYU,10
101,501412,1,555,DDGTH,11
102,502269,0,000,DDERF,60
103,508877,2,111,SDEFV,23
```

Comment: Can I use sed to achieve the same? I tried to find and print the match with this command ` testfile.txt | sed -n -r 's/^[0-9]*,[0-9]*,0/000/p'` but it replaces the whole part with 000. Is there any way to remember the position and then replace it

Comment: With awk it can be solved much more elegantly. It is also possible with sed: `sed 's/^\([^,]\+,[^,]\+,0,\)[^,]\+,/\1000,/' file`

Comment: Surely this is a duplicate