# Unix Shell : update a column value based on other colume value

Tags: shell, unix, awk

In unix, Have a file as below:

```
a,aaa,abc
b,bbb,abc
c,bbb,abc
d,xyz,abc
e,bbb,abc
f,ddd,abc
```

I want to update 3rd column value to `xyz`, if second column is `bbb`. Final result should look like:

```
a,aaa,abc
b,bbb,xyz
c,bbb,xyz
d,xyz,abc
e,bbb,xyz
f,ddd,abc
```

Comment: Cool. And have you tried anything?

Comment: tried, cut wih pipes, awk on my comp sys, but cant access stackoverflow from here, so posing from mobile, pls help. sorry if qs looked filled with attitude, didnt mean that :)

Comment: Share your attempts in the question

Comment: tried to explain above why i didnt posted that, its ok bro, if u dont wanna help, universe is huge and god is kind :)

Comment: See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47030770/change-a-column-based-on-another-column-value). It is not difficult to adapt it to your case. See also instructions in the answer. Good luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change a column based on another column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47030770/change-a-column-based-on-another-column-value)

Answer (score 1):

Using awk, set the FS (field separator) and OFS (output field separator variables to comma, test if $2 (the 2nd field) has the wanted value, and if yes set $3. Print every record.